# Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit not available

Tags: reference, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I have two solutions in VS2012 Professional on Windows8. In both I need to reference the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.
Both are WP8 Solution/Projects
I used NuGet to install the Toolkit and it was added to the references automatically. However, I switched to the other solution to add it as a reference there as well. But it is not available, allthough the NuGet Manager says, that the Toolkit is installed.
I restarted both solutions, but that didn't help.

I have all the Patches/Updates for VS2012 and Windows8 installed. Also NuGet is the latest version.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what could possibly have caused this, but suddenly in the second solution the NuGet Manager said it wasn't installed. So I installed it and it was automatically referenced.